# Alterar eixos X e Y gráficos ggplot no R

Tags: r

Gostaria de deixar o gráfico no ggplot de forma que a escala do eixo y, fique em milhões de toneladas, para assim os valores ficarem menores, e também que no eixo x, apareça todos os meses e anos.

Usei este código para rodar o gráfico

```
Data=seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=18)

PAbr=cbind(Data,PAbr)

ggplot(data = PAbr, aes(x = Data, y = Produção)) +

  geom_line(size=1)+ 

  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b/%Y") + theme_minimal()
```

E a minha base de dados são dados de bilhões de toneladas, por isso os dados não aparecem inteiros no eixo y, da forma que gostaria, por isso a ideia de alterar a escala.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso alguém saiba me ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(123)
PAbr <- data.frame(
  Data = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "1 month", length.out = 18),
  Produção = rnorm(18, 10^9, 10^8) )

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(PAbr, aes(Data, Produção/10^9)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  scale_x_date(NULL, date_labels = "%b/%y", date_breaks = "1 month") +
  scale_y_continuous("Produção (em milhões de toneladas)") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Comment: Carlos, poderia explicar melhor o argumento date_labels = %b/%y dentro da função scale_x_date( ) ? A "%" seguido de "b" classifica aquela posição como mês ou apenas faz referência à posição, sem atribuir a ela qualquer classe?

Comment: `date_breaks` especifica o intervalo de tempo a ser usado nos rótulos; para semestre seria "6 months". `date_labels` indica o formato de exibição; cheque `?strptime` para ver as opções.

Answer (score 2):

Só dando outra opção usando o ótimo exemplo de Carlos. Se você quiser algo mais complicado/diferente mudando os eixos você pode usar o pacote `scales`, que é o que o `ggplot` usa para criar os eixos.
Aqui crio uma função `transf_eixo` que específica que o eixo vai ser transformado em 1e-9, arredondado na primeira casa decimal e ter vírgula como separador. E depois aplico a função ao eixo y.
A função e o pacote possuem mais opções e formatos pra trabalhar, aí dão mais poder para deixar os eixos como você quer.

```
# Dados de exemplo de Carlos
set.seed(123)
PAbr <- data.frame(
  Data = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "1 month", length.out = 18),
  Produção = rnorm(18, 10^9, 10^8) )

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

transf_eixo <- number_format(scale = 1e-9, accuracy = .1, decimal.mark = ",")

ggplot(PAbr, aes(Data, Produção)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  scale_x_date(NULL, date_labels = "%b/%y", date_breaks = "1 month") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Produção (em milhões de toneladas)",
                     labels = transf_eixo) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar isto

```
p1 + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2, 4, 6))
```

O break são as escalas, tente colocar manualmente.

Comment: Ele não está aceitando quando coloco scale_y_continuous(breaks = c()), no parênteses do c, teria que colocar por exemplo, 10^9,10^8.. ele retorna essa mensagem: Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.